# ICO, transfering funds

Tags: solidity, web3js, ethers.js, remix, ico

I'm creating a simple ICO contract, it sends the amount of the token bought to the buyer as soon as the contract receives ether and then sent the received ether to a different wallet, I've been testing it on remix all day but, the contracts receives the ether but don't send out the ether to the wallet neither does the buyer received hers. Here's the buying function.

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity 0.8.19;
import "./SafeMath.sol";


interface IERC20 {
    function totalSupply() external view returns (uint);

    function balanceOf(address account) external view returns (uint);

    function transfer(address recipient, uint amount) external returns (bool);

    function allowance(
        address owner,
        address spender
    ) external view returns (uint);

    function approve(address spender, uint amount) external returns (bool);

    function transferFrom(
        address sender,
        address recipient,
        uint amount
    ) external returns (bool);

    event Transfer(address indexed from, address indexed to, uint value);
    event Approval(address indexed owner, address indexed spender, uint value);

    function burn(uint256 _value) external returns (bool success);
}

contract Crowdsale {
    using SafeMath for uint256;

    // The token being sold
    IERC20 public token;

    // Address where funds are collected
    IERC20 public wallet;

    // How many token units a buyer gets per wei
    uint256 public rate;

    // Amount of wei raised
    uint256 public weiRaised;

    /**
     * Event for token purchase logging
     * @param purchaser who paid for the tokens
     * @param beneficiary who got the tokens
     * @param value weis paid for purchase
     * @param amount amount of tokens purchased
     */
    event TokenPurchase(
        address indexed purchaser,
        address indexed beneficiary,
        uint256 value,
        uint256 amount
    );

    /**
     * @param _rate Number of token units a buyer gets per wei
     * @param _wallet Address where collected funds will be forwarded to
     * @param _token Address of the token being sold
     */

    constructor(uint256 _rate, address _wallet, address _token) {
        require(_rate > 0);
        require(_wallet != address(0));
        require(_token != address(0));

        rate = _rate;
        wallet = IERC20(_wallet);
        token = IERC20(_token);
    }

    /**
   * @dev fallback function ***DO NOT OVERRIDE***
  //  */
    fallback() external payable {
        buyTokens(msg.sender);
    }

    // receive() external payable{}

    /**
     * @dev low level token purchase ***DO NOT OVERRIDE***
     * @param _beneficiary Address performing the token purchase
     */
    function buyTokens(address _beneficiary) public payable {
        uint256 weiAmount = msg.value;
        _preValidatePurchase(_beneficiary, weiAmount);

        // calculate token amount to be created
        uint256 tokens = _getTokenAmount(weiAmount);

        // update state
        weiRaised = weiRaised.add(weiAmount);
        _processPurchase(_beneficiary, tokens);

        emit TokenPurchase(msg.sender, _beneficiary, weiAmount, tokens);

        _updatePurchasingState(_beneficiary, weiAmount);
        _forwardFunds();
        _postValidatePurchase(_beneficiary, weiAmount);
    }

    /**
     * @dev Validation of an incoming purchase. Use require statements to revert state when conditions are not met. Use super to concatenate validations.
     * @param _beneficiary Address performing the token purchase
     * @param _weiAmount Value in wei involved in the purchase
     */
    function _preValidatePurchase(
        address _beneficiary,
        uint256 _weiAmount
    ) internal pure {
        require(_beneficiary != address(0));
        require(_weiAmount != 0);
    }

    /**
     * @dev Validation of an executed purchase. Observe state and use revert statements to undo rollback when valid conditions are not met.
     * @param _beneficiary Address performing the token purchase
     * @param _weiAmount Value in wei involved in the purchase
     */
    function _postValidatePurchase(
        address _beneficiary,
        uint256 _weiAmount
    ) internal {
        // optional override
    }

    // 0x4815A8Ba613a3eB21A920739dE4cA7C439c7e1b1
    // 0x4B20993Bc481177ec7E8f571ceCaE8A9e22C02db
    /**
     * @dev Source of tokens. Override this method to modify the way in which the crowdsale ultimately gets and sends its tokens.
     * @param _beneficiary Address performing the token purchase
     * @param _tokenAmount Number of tokens to be emitted
     */
    function _deliverTokens(
        address _beneficiary,
        uint256 _tokenAmount
    ) internal {
        token.transfer(_beneficiary, _tokenAmount);
    }

    /**
     * @dev Executed when a purchase has been validated and is ready to be executed. Not necessarily emits/sends tokens.
     * @param _beneficiary Address receiving the tokens
     * @param _tokenAmount Number of tokens to be purchased
     */
    function _processPurchase(
        address _beneficiary,
        uint256 _tokenAmount
    ) internal {
        _deliverTokens(_beneficiary, _tokenAmount);
    }

    /**
     * @dev Override for extensions that require an internal state to check for validity (current user contributions, etc.)
     * @param _beneficiary Address receiving the tokens
     * @param _weiAmount Value in wei involved in the purchase
     */
    function _updatePurchasingState(
        address _beneficiary,
        uint256 _weiAmount
    ) internal {
        // optional override
    }

    /**
     * @dev Override to extend the way in which ether is converted to tokens.
     * @param _weiAmount Value in wei to be converted into tokens
     * @return Number of tokens that can be purchased with the specified _weiAmount
     */
    function _getTokenAmount(
        uint256 _weiAmount
    ) internal view returns (uint256) {
        return _weiAmount.mul(rate);
    }

    /**
     * @dev Determines how ETH is stored/forwarded on purchases.
     */
    function _forwardFunds() internal {
        // bool sent =  wallet.transfer(address(wallet),msg.value);
        wallet.transfer(address(wallet), msg.value);
        // require(sent, "Transaction failed");
    }

    function getWallet() public view returns (uint) {
        return address(wallet).balance;
    }

    function getTokenBalance() public view returns (uint) {
        return address(token).balance;
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you please update the question with the complete contract code?

Comment: Yes, I've done it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We need to agree on your goal first:

Anyone can purchase your token using the native coin of the chain at a rate you've predefined. Once someone successfully purchases the token then the amount of native coin accessible in the msg.value will be forwarded to a wallet you've also predefined.

Also, regarding how your contract is constructed, it seems you plan on deploying the ERC20 token separately from the Crowdsale contract. If not comment below that you want the Crowdsale to also deploy the ERC20 token.

After agreeing on the goal, there are multiple fixes needed to achieve it with the current code.

First, the deployment order and supply of ERC20 tokens:

1. Deploy an ERC20 contract - need the contract address to be able to deploy the Crowdsale contract (address _token)
2. Deploy this Crowdsale contract
3. Transfer the number of tokens you want to sell on this ICO to
   the Crowdsale.

Second, we need to fix parts of your contract to enable forwarding the native coin the buyer used in order to buy your token:

1. Currently, you set the type of the target wallet as IERC20 and this is incorrect. Because you want to transfer the native coin of the chain you need to set the type of the variable to Address because you simply are saving the target wallet address and not a contract.

```
    // Address where funds are collected
    address public wallet;
```

2. In the _forwardFunds function you want to transfer the ETH not an ERC20 token so the function should look something like this:

```
    /**
     * @dev Determines how ETH is stored/forwarded on purchases.
     */
    function _forwardFunds(uint256 _value) internal {
        // bool sent =  wallet.transfer(address(wallet),msg.value);
   address payable receiver = payable(wallet);
   receiver.transfer(_value);
        // require(sent, "Transaction failed");
    }
```

3. You should also add the receive function to be able to accept the native currency of the chain and for it to also appear correctly on the block explorers.
   [The differences between receive and fallback](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/81994/what-is-the-receive-keyword-in-solidity)
   :

```
    //Required to be able to accept native currency of the network(ETH)
    event Received(address, uint256);

    receive() external payable {
        emit Received(msg.sender, msg.value);
    }
```

The full code:

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity 0.8.19;
import "./SafeMath.sol";


interface IERC20 {
    function totalSupply() external view returns (uint);

    function balanceOf(address account) external view returns (uint);

    function transfer(address recipient, uint amount) external returns (bool);

    function allowance(
        address owner,
        address spender
    ) external view returns (uint);

    function approve(address spender, uint amount) external returns (bool);

    function transferFrom(
        address sender,
        address recipient,
        uint amount
    ) external returns (bool);

    event Transfer(address indexed from, address indexed to, uint value);
    event Approval(address indexed owner, address indexed spender, uint value);

    function burn(uint256 _value) external returns (bool success);
}

contract Crowdsale {
    using SafeMath for uint256;

    // The token being sold
    IERC20 public token;

    // Address where funds are collected
    address public wallet;

    // How many token units a buyer gets per wei
    uint256 public rate;

    // Amount of wei raised
    uint256 public weiRaised;

    /**
     * Event for token purchase logging
     * @param purchaser who paid for the tokens
     * @param beneficiary who got the tokens
     * @param value weis paid for purchase
     * @param amount amount of tokens purchased
     */
    event TokenPurchase(
        address indexed purchaser,
        address indexed beneficiary,
        uint256 value,
        uint256 amount
    );

    /**
     * @param _rate Number of token units a buyer gets per wei
     * @param _wallet Address where collected funds will be forwarded to
     * @param _token Address of the token being sold
     */

    constructor(uint256 _rate, address _wallet, address _token) {
        require(_rate > 0);
        require(_wallet != address(0));
        require(_token != address(0));

        rate = _rate;
        wallet = _wallet;
        token = IERC20(_token);
    }

    /**
   * @dev fallback function ***DO NOT OVERRIDE***
  //  */
    fallback() external payable {
        buyTokens(msg.sender);
    }

    //Required to be able to accept native currency of the network(ETH)
    event Received(address, uint256);

    receive() external payable {
        emit Received(msg.sender, msg.value);
        buyTokens(msg.sender);
    }

    /**
     * @dev low level token purchase ***DO NOT OVERRIDE***
     * @param _beneficiary Address performing the token purchase
     */
    function buyTokens(address _beneficiary) public payable {
        uint256 weiAmount = msg.value;
        _preValidatePurchase(_beneficiary, weiAmount);

        // calculate token amount to be created
        uint256 tokens = _getTokenAmount(weiAmount);

        // update state
        weiRaised = weiRaised.add(weiAmount);
        _processPurchase(_beneficiary, tokens);

        emit TokenPurchase(msg.sender, _beneficiary, weiAmount, tokens);

        _updatePurchasingState(_beneficiary, weiAmount);
        _forwardFunds();
        _postValidatePurchase(_beneficiary, weiAmount);
    }

    /**
     * @dev Validation of an incoming purchase. Use require statements to revert state when conditions are not met. Use super to concatenate validations.
     * @param _beneficiary Address performing the token purchase
     * @param _weiAmount Value in wei involved in the purchase
     */
    function _preValidatePurchase(
        address _beneficiary,
        uint256 _weiAmount
    ) internal pure {
        require(_beneficiary != address(0));
        require(_weiAmount != 0);
    }

    /**
     * @dev Validation of an executed purchase. Observe state and use revert statements to undo rollback when valid conditions are not met.
     * @param _beneficiary Address performing the token purchase
     * @param _weiAmount Value in wei involved in the purchase
     */
    function _postValidatePurchase(
        address _beneficiary,
        uint256 _weiAmount
    ) internal {
        // optional override
    }

    // 0x4815A8Ba613a3eB21A920739dE4cA7C439c7e1b1
    // 0x4B20993Bc481177ec7E8f571ceCaE8A9e22C02db
    /**
     * @dev Source of tokens. Override this method to modify the way in which the crowdsale ultimately gets and sends its tokens.
     * @param _beneficiary Address performing the token purchase
     * @param _tokenAmount Number of tokens to be emitted
     */
    function _deliverTokens(
        address _beneficiary,
        uint256 _tokenAmount
    ) internal {
        token.transfer(_beneficiary, _tokenAmount);
    }

    /**
     * @dev Executed when a purchase has been validated and is ready to be executed. Not necessarily emits/sends tokens.
     * @param _beneficiary Address receiving the tokens
     * @param _tokenAmount Number of tokens to be purchased
     */
    function _processPurchase(
        address _beneficiary,
        uint256 _tokenAmount
    ) internal {
        _deliverTokens(_beneficiary, _tokenAmount);
    }

    /**
     * @dev Override for extensions that require an internal state to check for validity (current user contributions, etc.)
     * @param _beneficiary Address receiving the tokens
     * @param _weiAmount Value in wei involved in the purchase
     */
    function _updatePurchasingState(
        address _beneficiary,
        uint256 _weiAmount
    ) internal {
        // optional override
    }

    /**
     * @dev Override to extend the way in which ether is converted to tokens.
     * @param _weiAmount Value in wei to be converted into tokens
     * @return Number of tokens that can be purchased with the specified _weiAmount
     */
    function _getTokenAmount(
        uint256 _weiAmount
    ) internal view returns (uint256) {
        return _weiAmount.mul(rate);
    }

    /**
     * @dev Determines how ETH is stored/forwarded on purchases.
     */
    function _forwardFunds() internal {
        // bool sent =  wallet.transfer(address(wallet),msg.value);
   address payable receiver = payable(wallet);
   receiver.transfer(msg.value);
        // require(sent, "Transaction failed");
    }

    function getWalletBalance() public view returns (uint) {
        return address(wallet).balance;
    }

    function getTokenBalance() public view returns (uint) {
        return address(token).balance;
    }

}
```

P.S:
Saw that your getWallet public function purpose is to fetch the wallet balance so I renamed it to getWalletBalance.

**Edit 1**:

I have successfully tested it end to end.
I used Remix for deployment and contract interaction and deployed it to the Mumbai network (Polygon testnet).[Link to the transaction](https://mumbai.polygonscan.com/tx/0xc72392fd8a016910f10f4913a8213545eacaa6d38eb61fafc1747188acc328ba)

Maybe you accidentally executed the buyTokens function without actually passing the native coin with a request? you need to change the value from default 0 to the requested amount, attaching an image:

[image: Set transaction native coin value]

**Edit 2**

You don't need to pass the msg.value, they are persistent through the life cycle of the transaction (my mistake, I've removed the section about that)

You need to trigger the buyTokens function on the receive & fallback functions if you want to trigger the purchase by only transferring native coins (ETH/MATIC and etc').

Comment: Yes you're right, and I've updated the contract but using Remix, i still cant transfer the native token to the wallet, and the ERC20 token  isn't transferred to the buyer, could it be the case of not using a proper testnet ?]

Comment: See the edit section I've added to the solution. Also, I'm assuming you are following the steps of deployment mentioned at the start of the solution for this to work.

Comment: These were my steps. I created an ERC token, used the token contract, and added another wallet address and the rate as a parameter for deploying the crowdsale contract. I then sent some token to the contract, then used another account to purchase the token by sending Eth to the crowdsale address, the crowdsale received the native token but it dint send it to the walletAddress neither did it send out the ERCtoken

Comment: I've added a fix (see edit2) for it to also work upon only native coins (ETH/MATIC and etc') to the contract.
If it still not working for you, please add if you are just sending the native coin to the contract or are triggering the buyTokens function and add a link for the transaction on the block explorer.

Comment: it still not working, I haven't deployed it on any testnet yet, all the transactions are done on remix VM. I have been using Remix accounts for testing

Comment: heresa link to the explorer https://mumbai.polygonscan.com/tx/0xaa35f2c5fe1caabc3ad9b2804cb18c1c0a33ff4206d64f17b498510f32310bda

Comment: I've checked the contract I wrote also on Remix with Mumbai and its working as it should: https://mumbai.polygonscan.com/tx/0xc72392fd8a016910f10f4913a8213545eacaa6d38eb61fafc1747188acc328ba  Maybe it's a human error on your side? Did you redeploy with the updated Crowdsale code and interact with the updated contract? Maybe the ERC20 token contract you are using is incorrect? Are you by accident interacting with one of the old contracts you deployed on Remix and not the new one?

Comment: Yes, I was interacting with the old contract and forgot to update the fallback function, can you please just take a look at my code, here's the remix link [ https://remix.ethereum.org/#lang=en&optimize=false&runs=200&evmVersion=null&version=soljson-v0.8.19+commit.7dd6d404.js&language=Solidity]

Comment: @Santos I've deployed to Mumbai and tested with an ERC20 token and its working :)
I checked with the buyTokens function and also just transferring the native coin to the contract.
https://mumbai.polygonscan.com/tx/0x12ede708b3e139b9de9c1f06db43f4cfefd8593958bf7c02379a4146d34bc0dc
https://mumbai.polygonscan.com/tx/0x647a2942afd73ea2d9c0d60629e31d3b39ca228eda0b46852211135bf452829f

Comment: Sorry it took this long, but thank you so much!

Comment: @Santos Of course, I am happy to help! 
Also, I would really appreciate it if you could accept my answer if it solved your problem or was the most helpful in finding your solution :)